# Automatic Java flow chart generator

Tags: java, flowchart

I'm just looking to see if anyone knows of any free safe automatic flow chart generators for software testing when you pass in java code that you have written. That's OK to download?

Comment: Not sure about flowchart, but ArgoUML is free and generates UML diagrams off of code, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But no, definitely a flow chart generator! I am familiar with them also but i'm finding it tricky to find one online to download for a flow chart! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[jgraphx](https://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is capable of rendering flowcharts (which are a special case of graphs in general) and have an open source offering.

there's a manual for it [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html)

Comment: That's JGraphX.  With an r.

Comment: This seems to be for rendering general flowcharts rather than automatically generating them when you pass in java code that you have written?